# Excel subroutine, transpose values delimited by comma to rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem, at work I was asked to take a data set and make some modifications. The problem is that there is one field which contains values `1,2,3,4-10,13-17,20`, and I have to expand the multiple ranges in the cell, transpose the figures into rows, and copy the rest of the row with it.

Example:

```
FIELD1 FIEL2 FIELD3 FIELD4
test1  test2 test3  1,2,3,4-10
```

should become:

```
FIELD1 FIEL2 FIELD3 FIELD4
test1  test2 test3  1
test1  test2 test3  2
test1  test2 test3  3
test1  test2 test3  4
test1  test2 test3  5
test1  test2 test3  6
```

and repeat the same for all the remaining rows until it will find an empty cell.

Below you can see my Frankenstein Subroutine which I have part developed, part stitched together from other sources. Problem is, this does partially work, but it doesn't do the job properly with more than one row. You can try:

```
Select the first cell and run the routine from a button
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

Any Help? Thanks in advance.

```
Sub Ops()

    'DECLARE VARIABLES
    Dim i As Long, st As String
    i = 1
    Dim startP As Range
    Dim c As Collection
    Dim count As Integer
    Set c = New Collection
    ary = Split(ActiveCell.Value, ",")

    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)
        count = 0

        For Each r In Selection
            If i = 1 Then
                st = r.Text
                i = 1
            Else
                st = st & "," & r.Text
            End If
        Next r

        Set startP = Selection(1, 2)
        ary = Split(st, ",")
        i = 1

        For Each a In ary
            count = count + 1
            startP(i, 1).Value = a
            i = i + 1
        Next a

        'COUNT MINUS 1
        scount = count - 1

        'REPEAT UNTIL REACH COUNT
        For ba = 1 To scount
            'COPY AND INSERT ROWS BELOW
            ActiveCell.Copy
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Next ba

        Selection.Offset(count, 1).Select

        'ONCE THE LOOP IS FINISH GO TO NEXT CELL
        Selection.Offset(0, -1).Select

    Loop

End Sub
```

You can see the data below

[image: You can see the data below]

In the Postcode cell, I need to expand the multiple ranges, and copy and insert below the same row Xtimes the number of postcodes in the cell.

Comment: I think you need to add more information. Is the data always like mentioned (so, four fields) and are the numbers always sorted as in the example data. Is there always a switch between single numbers and ranges like 3-7 and 10-17. And question to your code: Why didn't you declare all variables? And to be honest: What is your excat question? Or do you want us to give you code which is doing what you need. Because for me your code does not make any sense. The comments are useless because they are stating the obvious.

Comment: Thank you Storax for chipping in. I appreciate you. The data set structure will be the same always,  but the data in the cell, will change based on the countries, so there will be different number of postcodes for each country, but to be able to compare it and filter it, i will need to break the postcode cell into rows if that makes sense. I know this is a hard one.

Answer (score 0):

This code does what you require - please be aware I have no well-defined cell referencing, since we're basing it on ActiveCell, I've left Ranges as `Range` rather than `worksheet.Range`

```
Sub x()
Do While ActiveCell.Value2 <> ""
    If InStr(1, ActiveCell.Value2, ",") > 0 Or InStr(1, ActiveCell.Value2, "-") > 0 Then e
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
End Sub
Sub e()

Dim a As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim rc As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim x() As String
Dim t() As String

    x = Split(ActiveCell, ",")
    r = ActiveCell.Row
    c = ActiveCell.Column


    For i = LBound(x) To UBound(x)
        If InStr(1, x(i), "-") Then
            a = a + Split(x(i), "-")(1) - Split(x(i), "-")(0)
        End If
    Next i

    a = a + UBound(x)
    Range(Cells(r + 1, c), Cells(r + a, c)).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

    For i = LBound(x) To UBound(x)
        t = Split(x(i), "-")
        If UBound(t) = 0 Then
            Cells(r + rc, c).Value2 = t(0)
            rc = rc + 1
        Else
            For j = t(0) To t(1)
                Cells(r + rc, c).Value2 = j
                rc = rc + 1
            Next j
        End If
    Next i

    Range(Cells(r, c - 3), Cells(r + rc - 1, c - 1)).Value2 = _
        Range(Cells(r, c - 3), Cells(r, c - 1)).Value2

End Sub
```

This basically fills that column one by one based on the numbers `x,y,a-b,z` by splitting first on `,` and then on any instances of `-`

After that, it's already got the row counter `rc` so just uses that counter to flood the range top to bottom, duplicating values in the 3 columns before the active cell

EDIT: I added 5 lines which actually goes through the ranges (1,2,4-7 whatever) to count how many rows to `INSERT` before actually filling in the information.

EDIT2: I added another sub routine called `x` to make this `e` routine loop until it reaches a cell with nothing in it... So to get the whole sheet fixed up, just highlight the uppermost cell with a range like (1,3,4-7... etc) and run the `x` routine

Comment: Actually wait, I just saw your data set and realised you need to insert some rows first...

Comment: Sorry Jamheadart can you give me some details about what you mean? Thanks

Comment: I didn't realise there was data under the activecell that needed moved down with an insert first, I've changed the code so that it will count how many rows are required to insert, do the insert and THEN run the rest of the code where it fills numbers and duplicates the previous column info.

Comment: This one does the job for one, but it doesn't add new rows, and loop trough the whole column, any idea?

Comment: The whole thing now just needs looped so that once it's finished the activecell becomes the next row with those ranges (1,2,4-7 etc) - I didn't see from your original code this just goes through everything, I thought you were just doing one cell/row at a time

Comment: Please see "EDIT 2" in my answer

Comment: No probs, fun challenge, I just wish I'd understood the entire problem from the outset instead of having to clag on some fixes afterwards!

Comment: Ok Pal, it did work, but after a bit a message comes up saying Subscript out of range. Any Idea why?

Comment: Must be due to some numbers that aren't fitting the usual patterns - it'll be trying to define a range that doesn't exist - do you know which line of data this is happening on?

Comment: It seems that the script runs until it find an empty cell, however the errors happen if there is a cell which contains 1,2,3,4, instead 1,2,3,4. The last comma creates the issue, the script split and transpose it with a space, then it gives the error.

Comment: We'd need a way to ignore blank entries (that is, a blank entry is created after the last comma) - will update code shortly

Comment: what if, after last comma there is a symbol, like an exclamation mark, or a dash or forward slash, because i think it will minimize human error when inputting the data

Comment: can test if it is a number with `isnumeric`

Comment: I think there should be a piece of code like this =LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-(RIGHT(A1)=",")) which will remove commas, and dash, what do you recon?

Comment: Sounds good, could try this one `=IF(ISNUMBER(RIGHT(A1,1)),A1,LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1))` which remove ANY last character if it isn't a number

Comment: Yes this one is good too, but do you have a way to implement it in the sub routine?

Comment: The script worked at the end thanks. To make sure it doesn't encounter errors like trailing commas this formula need to be run before running the script: =LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-(RIGHT(A1)=",")); then you have to copy and paste the results onto another column and then you can run finally the scrip. One more thing the script gives error where it find double or triple commas like this' 1,2,,3,4-8,9. But I did find and replaced them so is a little bit of work before making the script run smoothly. Again thanks